# Creating list from argument list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, arguments

Is there a way to cast argument list into list?

Somthing like:

```
list(*arguments)
```

Dosen't work because list() take at most 1 argument...

im trying to cast tuple of tuples into a list

```
list(('a', *('b', 5))
```

dosent work at all...

Comment: how about just `list(arguments)`?

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(arguments)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a tuple of tuples, eg,

```
a = ((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))
```

Getting it into a list depends on what list you are expecting - you can pass the tuple straight into `list` (it takes any iterable) to get a list of tuples:

```
>>> list(a)
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

If instead you want a flattened list, you want [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) - it gives you a generator, but you can pass *that* into `list` to get a list:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you want a list of lists, you want a list comprehension:

```
>>> [list(b) for b in a]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

To flatten a heterogenous tuple of tuples and single values, it gets a little more complicated - what you want to do is turn all the single values into single-length tuples or lists, and then it's the same as the `chain` example above. If you only want to flatten the tuples, and not, eg, nested lists, you could do this:

```
>>> a = ('a', ('b', 'c'))
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(b if isinstance(b, tuple) else [b] for b in a))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Does chain() support mixing integers with chars? (chain('a', 5))

Comment: @Jah yes, though not quite like that. It doesn't care what's *in* any of the iterables you give it, but all of its arguments have to be iterables (strings are, ints aren't) - `list(chain('a', [5]))` gives `['a', 5]`.